# Fixing problems in latin transliteration of acute accented Cyrillic vowels with \directlua

Tags: luatex, accents, cyrillic, directlua

A good transliteration method from Cyrillic to Latin characters using XeLaTeX is discussed in [Using XeTeX for automatic transliteration of Cyrillic letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/using-xetex-for-automatic-transliteration-of-cyrillic-letters)

Actually I'm using LuaLaTeX. the transliteration can be done by the use of `\directlua` as suggested by @DavidCarlisle in this post, [Create a mapping for transliteration from Cyrillic to Latin in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285610/create-a-mapping-for-transliteration-from-cyrillic-to-latin-in-lualatex), which is actually the root post of this Question.

The present Question discuss the problems of the method suggested by @DavidCarlisle in this post, [Create a mapping for transliteration from Cyrillic to Latin in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285610/create-a-mapping-for-transliteration-from-cyrillic-to-latin-in-lualatex), which uses `\directlua`.

General problems arise from the fact that Unicode system does not provide acute accented vowels, which are formed by the use of the "combining acute accent" character (`\char"0301`).

**1. General accentuation problem**

Both XeTeX and LuaTeX print in a wrong manner non transliterated acute accented capital Cyrillic letters, because of a bug in the font I used (Linux Libertine O). This maybe fixed as posted in this Answer: [Misplaced Accents in Cyrillic Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/misplaced-accents-in-cyrillic-text), but it forces to modify the text manually replacing, for example, Е́ with '{E}.

**2. Transliteration of acute accented Э́**

The combination of "combining acute accent" and Ė it seems a hard work to get!

**3. The true problem: transliteration of a predefined text string**

It seems`\directlua` transliteration does not apply to a text defined in the preamble.

All of these problems are shown in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\def\textsample{Здравствуй, Мир} 


\begin{document}

    \textsample \par
    Здравствуй, Мир \par
    Э э    Э́ э́ \par \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \directlua{require("cyrtr2")}
    Transliteration by \verb\directlua\ \vspace{\baselineskip} 
    
    \textsample \par
    Здравствуй, Мир \par
    Э э    Э́ э́ \\    %problems if transliterated with 'Ė ė'

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem with accents on capital letters is apparently a problem with the libertine font, as noted in your other question.

The transliteration would apply to the preamble if you did

```
\directlua{require("cyrtr2")}
```

earlier.

Probably you are looking for

```
\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
"process_input_buffer",
"cyrillic transliteration")
```

to turn it off as well as

```
\directlua{
luatexbase.add_to_callback(
"process_input_buffer",
cyrtr,
"cyrillic transliteration")}
```

to turn it back on (you don't need to input the file with the big mapping each time)

Comment: The suggestion was clear and efficient. Thank you, @DavidCarlisle. As you can understand from my problems, I'm not expert in lua! I actually found another problem with the transliteration method involving acute accented letter 'и' 'i'. I put the Question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286112/lualattex-inefficiency-in-transliteration-from-cyrillic-of-acute-accented-vowels