# Fixing the matching between combining accents and capital cyrillic letters

Tags: unicode, accents, cyrillic

This question, which is a prosecution of the debate in [Misplaced Accents in Cyrillic Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/misplaced-accents-in-cyrillic-text) answered by @egreg, wishes to focus on the mechanism of combination of a combining accent (e.g. combining acute accets 0301) with an uppercase.

When you have to add an acute accent to a cyrillic uppercase Lua/Xe-LaTex joints the given capital letter to the combining acute accent unicode character (U+0301), because in the Unicode chart there is no given glyph for any cyrillic acute accented capital vowel.

This combination comes however with an error for a variety of font sets, as the following code demonstrates:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,openright,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\def\CyrillicAccents{А а А́ а́ \\ Е е Е́ е́ \\ И и И́ и́ \\ О о О́ о́ \\ У у У́ у́ \\ Ы ы Ы́ ы́ \\ Э э Э́ э́ \\ Ю ю   Ю́ ю́ \\ Я я Я́ я́}

\begin{document}

\fontspec{Linux Libertine}

\noindent\CyrillicAccents

\end{document}
```

The acute accent does not match the height of the capital letters.

[image]

This might be caused by an error in the font set, but if the same set of accented vowels is edited in MS Word or Pages (or Open Office, I guess) the result is without bugs:

[image]

It seems that XeLaTeX does not find the correct informations to correctly place the accents, while other editors do.

Which is the method of joining a letter to a combining character? How to control the parameters of this process?

Comment: I added a workaround in the linked question